# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-3}\int_0^{x^2}\sin{(\sqrt t)}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I use the fundemental theorem of calculus
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^{x^2}\sin{(\sqrt t)}dt}{x^3}=\frac{F_{(x^2)}-F_{(0)}}{x^3}="\frac{0}{0}"
$$

Than apply L'hopital rule

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f_{(x^2)}-f_{(0)}}{3x^2}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sqrt x^2)-\sin(0)}{3x^2}=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{3x^2}="\frac{0}{0}"
$$

Than L'hopital again:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{6x}
$$

This limit does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure the limit is not as $x\to0^+$?

Comment: Yes. maybe the professor got it wrong but that's what's written on the test from a few years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When differentiating your integral, you forget to apply the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}\sin(\sqrt{t})\,dt=\sin(\sqrt{x^2})\cdot\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\sin (|x|)\cdot 2x.
$$
(In the end, you will conclude that the limit does not exist.)

Comment: If we add the restriction that $x\to0^+$, then the limit will exist and equals $2/3$, no?

Comment: @Clayton Yes indeed, but that is not how the question is stated.

Comment: I'm not used to the $\frac{d}{dx}$ notations, can you explain why I need to apply the chain rule when doing the derivative?

Comment: $\int_0^{x^2}\sin(\sqrt{t})\,dt$ is a composition $f(g(x))$ where $f(u)=\int_0^u\sin(\sqrt{t})\,dt$ and $g(x)=x^2$. Thus, when we differentiate, we get $f'(g(x))g'(x)$. It is the $g'(x)$ part you forgot.

Comment: @Clayton The range of integration is $[0,x^2]$, so $t\geq 0$ independent of the sign of $x$. Thus, no complex analysis is needed (I guess you feared the $\sqrt{t}$). In fact, one could first note that the expression is odd in $x$, so either the limit is $0$, or it does not exist. In this case it is the latter case that is true.

Comment: Ah, so true! I saw the $\sqrt{t}$ and was not thinking properly.

Comment: Once we apply l'Hopital once we're left with the following limit $\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin{x}/3x=2/3$. Or am I missing something

Comment: @marwalix Yes, you miss an absolute value inside the sine.

Comment: So we have $2/3$ as a limit when $x\to 0^+$ and $-2/3$ when $x\to 0^-$. Means no limit at $0$ but a right limit and a left limit